# Different between $\mu$ and $T_{00}$ in perfect fluid solutions?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In the perfect fluid solution for general relativity, you get

$$T_{ab} = u_a u_b (\mu + p) - g_{ab} \, p$$

I've seen varying descriptions of what $\mu$ is, and some places describe it as the local energy density. But I also thought that $T_{00}$ was the energy density.

So, what is the physical interpretation and difference between these two quantities? Because they are clearly not equal.

Comment: For the record, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_solution) appears to claim that it's the 'matter density'.

Comment: MTW refers to both as "mass-energy density".

Comment: I'd take MTW over Wikipedia, though they seem similar.

Comment: But that doesn't help! They are not equal quantities :(

Answer (score 1):

If we work in the rest frame of the fluid then $u_0 = 1$. In that case the formula for $T_{00}$ gives:

$$ T_{00} = (\mu + p) + \eta_{00}p = (\mu + p) - p = \mu $$

So $T_{00}$ is just the energy density $\mu$ as you say.